# Firestore offline batch delete

Tags: firebase, offline, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase and firestore and would like to know if the behavior I found is a bug or by design.
I am using angularfire2 in my ionic project where the user will be offline most of the time… so offline support is a big deal.

The problem: `snapshotChanges` is not called in a offline batch delete of subcolletion.

I have something like this in firestore `/users/{userId}/projects/{projectId}/points/{pointId}`

When a user inserts a new project or point a use `set` and the object is written fine, my lists are updated with the new instance and it works great thanks to `snapshotChanges`. When the user removes a project is the problem.. 
I execute a batch delete in the points of a project and after that I delete the project itself. This works fine online, but not offline. My lists are not being updated even though the operation completes with success. I could reproduce it multiple times, but only if the app is offline all the time ( the inserts and deletes are only local)

am I missing something?
The documentation states [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions):

> Batched writes have fewer failure cases than transactions and use
>   simpler code. They are not affected by contention issues, because they
>   don't depend on consistently reading any documents. Batched writes
>   execute even when the user's device is offline.

This "Batched writes execute even when the user's device is offline" this makes me understand that the events of removal should be propagated to `snapshotChanges`.

Comment: Can you add a minimal repro here? Seems like this should work fine, so probably something in the details or AngularFire related.

Comment: Here https://github.com/BugsBunnyBR/firestore-ionic I included a youtube video of me trying to explain what is happening.

Comment: This is a pretty big repro. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's a lot to take in, but I'm fairly sure this is expected behavior. The delete op callbacks shouldn't complete until the server comes back and the delete is saved remotely. Which means that anything in your deletion callbacks won't trigger unless you restore the connection. Similarly, I'm really sure what is going on with subItemCol()--hard to follow all this--but if it hasn't been saved locally before going offline, it can't be queried.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @SantiArias, yes. I just used `forkJoin` to request the deletion of all items and subitems